# Importing node-fetch module into a CDK project

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-cdk, node-fetch

I have been trying to get the node-fetch module in a CDK project.
So that i can use it in a Lambda function.

The dependency is in the package.json file.
[image: npm list]
I installed it in the node package manager.
[image: error]
I keep getting: Cannot find module 'node-fetch.

I have looked at: https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/issues/1027
But this didn't seem to work.

Function definition:

```js
const lambdaJiraApi = new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda_Jira_api', {
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  code: Code.fromAsset('lambda'),
  handler: 'apiJiraFetcher.handler',
  timeout: Duration.seconds(20),
  functionName: 'lambda_Jira_api',
  environment: { QUEUEURL: queueSQS.queueUrl },
  layers: [nodeFetchLayer],
});
```

```
var fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

Comment: How is your Lambda Function construct defined?  Please add a text codeblock.  [It's best to avoid images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557) in questions.

Comment: const lambdaJiraApi = new lambda.Function(this, "lambda_Jira_api",{
      runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
      code: Code.fromAsset("lambda"),
      handler: "apiJiraFetcher.handler",
      timeout: Duration.seconds(20),
      functionName: "lambda_Jira_api",
      environment: {
        QUEUEURL: queueSQS.queueUrl
      },
      layers: [nodeFetchLayer]
    });

Comment: sorry i don't know how to print it out nicely on Stackoverflow

Comment: No worries.  I added it to your question.  How are you importing the `nodeFetch` module in your code?  Please edit your question with the `require` or `import` line of code from your handler.